# Notepad ++ line replace

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible in Notepad++ to select a line and replace the selected line in all the files I have open?

If I have on 2 lines the same text, is it possible to replace that text only on a certain line?

Is it possible to do it in more than 1 file at once?

Comment: Related(ish): [Replace text at specific line number with other text using notepad++](http://superuser.com/questions/1094574/replace-text-at-specific-line-number-with-other-text-using-notepad/1094582#1094582)

Answer (score 1):

To [replace the selected line in all opened files](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/) you need to do 2 steps:

- Select the line you want to replace and do "Find in files":

[image]

- Replace in all opened files:

[image]

Comment: if you want to match only a newline instead of a word, you can use \r\n as "find what" and change the search mode to "Extended". (search for regular expressions for more info)

Comment: He also asks if it is possible to replace only the text in line 12 but not 14 if they were both the same. This answer is not answering that part of the question.

Comment: If you want to replace only **some** of the lines, then use "Find Next" and "Replace" on only the lines you want to change. I don't think this can be further automated as a manual decision is required.