# Batch replacing a single line of text in multiple text documents

Tags: batch, notepad++, text-editing

I have a ton (thousands) of text documents i would like to edit and really don't want to edit them one by one each document has the the same layout and it looks like this

```
Artist: anonymous 

Title: a2f1f6741ffbe71e301a5f1d18057a45

Date Posted: 03-02-2016 12.15

Tags: absurdres bare_tree brick_wall building cloud highres   no_humansorange_sky original outdoors puddle rugiadian scenery shadow sky skyline skyscraper snow sunset tree wall wallpaper winter

Series: original

Character: unknown
```

i would like to edit line 4 (Tags) by deleting the space in between each word and adding a /

how would i go about doing this ?
would i be able to do it in notepad++ or would i need to get another piece of software
?

Comment: See the chosen answer for this SE question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115508/batch-find-and-edit-lines-in-txt-file    It uses VB but could be amended for what you want... You'll need to look out for the very first space because it separates your identifier with the list of tags so you'll need to miss this out.

Comment: The best utility for batch text edits is `sed`: this a Unix utility and there are numerous Windows ports (just search for `sed.exe`). It handles regular expressions, so any edits you perform in NotePad++ can be done with it.

Comment: I can speak to `SED` being a reliable tool once you get the syntax worked out for your need. There also used to be a (file and replace tool) F.A.R.T tool that worked rather solid with Windows for similar need. Are you trying to upload text document or Word documents? You mention text documents but have the post tagged as Microsoft-Word.

Comment: Check this out perhaps: http://superuser.com/questions/1094574/replace-text-at-specific-line-number-with-other-text-using-notepad/1094582